# Matlab imread function confusion

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, imread

I'm implementing an ant colony algorithm in a grayscale image, and I'm confused in getting the right heuristic values. I always get 0 or 1.

Here's the part of the code:

```
x = imread('test.jpg');

y = max(x(:));
```

For example, I get 226 as the max intensity value. I try x/y and I get a matrix with values of 1's and mostly 0's on single digit intensity values. Is there a part here I'm missing?

I tried creating a zero 4x4 matrix with 255 in the diagonal. Then I divide it with y. I get some "same integer class error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the image type of the image you are reading in with `imread` is one of an unsigned integer type, most likely `uint8` and so when you are performing division, it is actually performing integer division and so the "decimal values" are truncated or removed.  Here's a reproducible example.  Let's say I had the following 2 x 2 image in `uint8` format:

```
>> A = uint8([1 2; 3 4])

A =

    1    2
    3    4
```

Now if I tried to divide each intensity image by 4, I get:

```
>> B = A / 4

B =

    0    1
    1    1
```

This is because the image type is `uint8` and so when division happens and the result is a floating-point number, the result is **rounded**, and this is most likely what is happening in your situation.

---

If you want to maintain floating point precision, you need to explicitly cast the image to `double`:

```
x = imread('test.jpg');
x = double(x); %// Change
y = max(x(:));
out = x / y;
```

BTW, since you want to normalize the image so that it falls in the range of `[0,1]`, I highly recommend you **do not do this** and use the [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) function instead.  It will perform this normalization for you as well as make other sanity checks:

```
x = imread('test.jpg');
out = im2double(x);
```

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. I found that there was something wrong when I tried an actual grayscale image instead a simple 255-diagonal.I actually still have to compute the difference of a pixel's neighbors, but thanks for suggesting im2double.

Comment: I'm confused. Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. My code is running fine now. Casting the image into double was what I needed.

Comment: Great. If you no longer need help, please consider accepting my answer to let the community know you no longer need help. That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my answer, to the left below the up and down voting arrows. Good luck!